# What is Transparency in Distributed Systems in simple words?

Tags: networking, internet

Can anyone explain in simple words what is transparency in Distributed Systems? I can't understand what it actually is in practice.
Here is what I have found:

> Transparency: The distributed systems should be perceived as a single entity by
>   the users or the application programmers rather than as a collection of
>   autonomous systems, which are cooperating. The users should be unaware of
>   where the services are located and also the transferring from a local machine to a
>   remote one should also be transparent.

Why should systems be perceived as a single entity by the users? What is the reason for that? Also, please give a realistic example in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implications of transparency are a major influence on the design of the system software.

**Transparency** in simple words is defined as the concealment from the user and the application programmer of the separation of components in a distributed system, so that the system is perceived as a whole rather than as a collection of independent components.

**Access transparency** enables local and remote resources to be accessed using identical operations.

**Location transparency** enables resources to be accessed without knowledge of their physical or network location (for example, which building or IP address).

**Failure transparency** enables the concealment of faults, allowing users and application programs to complete their tasks despite the failure of hardware or software components

**Concurrency transparency** enables several processes to operate concurrently using shared resources without interference between them.

To give a realistic example, imagine when a website gets hacked and in their homepage appears "we  have been hacked... wait till we fix the problem" that does not have **Failure transparency**. You would want to perceive  the users that the system is being updated to hide the fact that their system is "weak" and has been hacked.

You would want to act as a whole rather than as a collection of independent components for transparency.

Comment: Isn't _concealment_ the exact opposite of _transparency_?  When used in most other contexts, transparency means openness and honesty.  Any idea why this term was chosen instead of something like "black-boxing" or similar?

Comment: To expand a bit—from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_(behavior)): "transparency [...] is operating in such a way that it is easy for others to see what actions are performed".  It seems that in distributed systems it means the exact opposite: making it hard for others to see exactly what is happening...  Weird.